# How to add image in Jquery Mobile button?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

My html5 code is

```
<div class="renew">
     <button><img src="images/btn.png"/>Renew Your Policy</button>
</div>
```

I want to add this image in left side of button using jquery mobile library but the image is not displaying.can anyone help me to do this task? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.renew button').before($('.renew img'))​;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wC9VS/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Custom Icons" section of [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html)

Comment: Hi i dont want to add icon. i want to add external image inside the button.Is it possible??

Comment: No image is in left hand side and button text is in the  middle inside the button. is it possible??

Comment: @EktaShukla, you can still use the "Custom Icons" link provided by davids. And just override existing jquery mobile CSS to make your text center inside the button. i think it has something to do with the padding in the ".ui-btn-icon-left .ui-btn-inner" style rule.